# Join 3 tables to display certain data PHP-MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, join

so i have this tables and i want to get certain datas for user to view and be able to POST to other page

i cant post images so i have to break this down so please bear with me

1st table

- dbo.users
- pkey(UserID)
- EmployeeName

2nd table

- dbo.PC
- pkey(PCID)
- PC_Number

3rd table

- dbo.FA_PC
- pkey(FAID)
- fkey(UserID)
- fkey(PCID)

how could i display the PC_Number of the currently selected $rs->Fields('UserID') in the same form and still be able to post it on printd.php

i dont know how to connect the dbo.users->dbo.FA_PC->dbo.PC

```
<form action="printd.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
   try {
   $myServer = "WTCPHFILESRV\WTCPHINV";
   $myUser = "sa";
   $myPass = "P@ssw0rd";
   $myDB = "wtcphitinventory";   
   $connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$myServer.";UID=".$myUser.";PWD=".$myPass.";DATABASE=".$myDB;
   $conn->open($connStr); 
         if (! $conn) {
            throw new Exception("Could not connect!");
        }
   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Error (File:): ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
   }

if (!$conn)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}

    $sql_exp = "select * from dbo.users"; 

  $rs = $conn->Execute($sql_exp);
echo "<select name='empt'>";
   while (!$rs->EOF) {
       set_time_limit(0);
        echo "<option value=".$rs->Fields('UserID')." >".$rs->Fields('EmployeeName')."</option>";

      $rs->MoveNext();
   }       
   $rs->Close();   



       ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

the join will look like this,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.PC_Number
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN FA_PC b
            ON a.UserID = b.UserID
        INNER JOIN PC c
            ON b.PCID = c.PCID
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: how could i put it on php? i mean post the details that i need