# displaying a data from database with 3 table joining together

Tags: php, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Join 3 tables to display certain data PHP-MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617873/join-3-tables-to-display-certain-data-php-mssql)

I have these tables and I want to get certain datas for user to view and be able to POST to other page

I cant post images so I have to break this down, so please bear with me

```
1st table     
 - dbo.users
 - pkey(UserID)
 - EmployeeName

2nd table    
 - dbo.PC
 - pkey(PCID)
 - PC_Number

3rd table
 - dbo.FA_PC    
 - pkey(FAID)
 - fkey(UserID)
 - fkey(PCID)

<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
try {
    $myServer = "WTCPHFILESRV\WTCPHINV";
    $myUser = "sa";
    $myPass = "P@ssw0rd";
    $myDB = "wtcphitinventory";
    $connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$myServer.";UID=".$myUser.";PWD=".$myPass.";DATABASE=".$myDB;
    $conn->open($connStr);
    if (! $conn) {
        throw new Exception("Could not connect!");
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error (File:): ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
}

if (!$conn)
{
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}

$sql_exp = "select * from dbo.users";
$rs = $conn->Execute($sql_exp);
echo "<select name='empf'>";
while (!$rs->EOF) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo "<option value=".$rs->Fields('UserID')." >".$rs->Fields('EmployeeName')."</option>";
    $rs->MoveNext();
}
$rs->Close();
?>
```

How could I display the `PC_Number` of the currently selected `$rs->Fields('UserID')` in the same form and still be able to post it on printd.php

Comment: Didn't you just ask this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617873/join-3-tables-to-display-certain-data-php-mssql/14617887#14617887

Comment: sorry my friend double posted it
just need a concrete answer :)
we are just students xD

Comment: Have a look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Try INNER JOINS

```
select A.*,B.*,C.* from table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.userid=B.userid 
INNER JOIN table3 C ON C.pcid=B.pcid where A.userid='2'
```

Good luck